Seamlessly using maps with different comparators
I was using an alias to refer to one of two maps:
map<int, int> & map_alias = use_map_a ? map_a : map_b;


but then changed map_b to use std::greater as its comparator (instead of the default std::less).
As expected, this line of code no longer works because map_alias/map_a/map_b are not all the same type.  Is there some simple workaround to allow an alias (or a similar and simple approach) to continue to be used?  I would just like the subsequent code to operate generically without needing to know which of the two maps it's operating on, and without needing to constuct a huge umbrella infrastructure to make it happen.
Using union/tuple/variant/std::any wouldn't really solve anything, since the map type would still need to be known in order to access the map from those objects.
Limitations: I'm using C++14 and so constexpr cannot be used in the solution.  It would be nice not to have to use SFINAE unless necessary.  Also I don't have access to boost.
I've spent several hours looking for a solution, so thanks in advance!

std::variant would solve the problem, but you would have to rewrite the code that uses map_alias to run within std::visit. Still, that's C++17.

You can make them into one type by passing comparator via constructor instead of template parameter:
std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> map_a{std::less<int>{}};
std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> map_b{std::greater<int>{}};
bool use_map_a = true;
auto& map_alias = use_map_a ? map_a : map_b;

std::function is a bit expensive, because internally it has to type erase all callable types. You could use function pointer, but for that you can't use std::less and std::greater:
bool myLess(int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
}
std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> map_a{myLess};

//or with lambda
std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> map_b{[](int a, int b){return a > b;}};



Thanks -- I used the lambda version and it works great!

Curious though -- what is "erase all callable types"?  Sounds bad ...

@Gymkata that's type-erasure. it means drop all properties of a type and keep track of interesting properties by paying some memory overhead. For std::function the interesting properties are invocation and lifetime management. For std::any it's just the lifetime.

You might rework your code and use template:
template <typename Map>
void foo(Map& m) // or even std::map<MyKey, MyValue, Comp>
{
    // ...
}

and then
if (use_map_a) {
   foo(map_a);
} else {
   foo(map_b);
}

